# Xbox 360: Installing games, whats the point?

Tags: xbox-360

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I install Xbox 360 games to my hard drive?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/719/should-i-install-xbox-360-games-to-my-hard-drive)

Other than "saving" the disc drive from extra wear and tear, what is the point in installing a game to the disk drive? There is no performance benefits. A slow loading game is still slow when installed. What's the deal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from wear and tear on the disc there are performance benefits for some games (not older ones because they were made before the install technology was made available) and the benefit of saving the optical reader for your disc drive.

Most newer games will increase performance because the 360 (as with most computing products) reads quicker off a hard drive than a disc and processing it that way (assuming  it's not a slow RPM drive).

You may want to read through some of the answers here as they highlight other points:
[Should I install Xbox 360 games to my hard drive?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/719/should-i-install-xbox-360-games-to-my-hard-drive)

Answer (score 0):

The most important benefit is that the DVD isn't spinning.

Since this is the source of extreme noise on the 360 (just compare it to the PS3 in this regard) this is a HUGE benefit IMHO. The slim version is better but it is still a major source of noise if you don't install the game.

Answer (score 0):

Basically on pre-slim models so that you don't have something that sounds like the flight deck of an aircraft carrier in the corner of your room. Loud DVD.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with everyone here the main benefit for installing your games onto pre-slim Xbox 360s is to reduce the noise it makes spinning **drastically**, also I have noticed slightly reduced loading times on some games e.g. Fallout New Vegas.

Very important note: There are some early 360 games that actually become slower if you install them e.g. Halo 3

I hope this helps