# Are there any risks associated with installing a game to the Xbox 360 hard drive?

Tags: xbox-360, hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I install Xbox 360 games to my hard drive?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/719/should-i-install-xbox-360-games-to-my-hard-drive)

I am playing the game Batman: Arkham City, and I am considering installing it to my hard drive.

Should I do it or not?  It seems risky to my Xbox 360.

Comment: Why would something stop working? And what do you mean by installing the game on the hard drive?

Comment: @Marcelo The Xbox 360 dashboard provides the ability to install a disc-based game to the hard drive. It basically just copies the contents of the disc to the hard drive. The disc still needs to be in the drive to start up the game, but all game data is loaded from the hard drive instead of the disc.

Comment: @Adeese agent86 tidied up the question because it was a big mess before. My comment was in response to the original question.

Answer (score 3):

There's very little risk to either your game disc or your hard drive if you install a disc-based game to the Xbox 360's hard drive.

If the disc has issues (ie, scratches or is defective in spots) it is possible that the install will fail, but it is unlikely that the install will cause these issues.  Installing to the hard drive actually causes less wear to the disc in the long run.

Similarly, the hard drive in the Xbox 360 is designed to be read and written many, many times over, and copying the game data to the drive does not cause any undue wear to it.  If the drive is having issues, it's possible that installing the game will expose these issues, but again, it's not any more likely to cause issues than any other use of the drive.