# Is it possible to copy an Xbox 360 game to a storage device?

Tags: xbox-360

I have an Xbox 360 game that I want to copy to my storage device, but I can't figure out how, if it is even possible.

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 8):

Have you taken these steps (from [MS Support](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/audio-video-setup-and-use/install-play-delete-game))?

> Install a game on your hard drive
>
> 1.Insert the game disc into the disc drive.
>
> Note After you insert the disc, the default action is to automatically
>   start the game. If this happens, exit the game and return to the Xbox
>   Dashboard.
>
> 2.From the Home hub, select the game in the drive tray, and then press X
>   on your controller.
>
> 3.Select Install.
>
> 4.A progress indicator appears while
>   your game is being installed on your hard drive.
>
> Note Installing an Xbox 360 game might take 12 minutes.

The disk is still required to play (needs to be inserted into the Xbox360).

Here is another question listing [benefits/downsides of installing games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/719/should-i-install-xbox-360-games-to-my-hard-drive).

Comment: Is the disc still required after this is done?

Comment: I think the OP wants to play the game without the disc, which I don't think is possible.