# XBOX 360 Play game from USB without DVD

Tags: xbox-360

I have my XBOX 360 games installed on my USB flash disk but when I try to play the game, XBOX prompts me for inserting DVD.

Is it possible to play game without DVD inside the drive? I have 4 games installed on my USB flash disk and I want to switch between games whenever I want without changing DVDs.

Comment: Potentially related question "[why should I install Xbox 360 games](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/719/should-i-install-xbox-360-games-to-my-hard-drive)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot play 360 Games without the disc if that's how they were originally installed. If you buy a digital title and then move it to a USB drive you can play it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it.
You could install the game and sell the disc.
Microsoft wouldn't be making a lot of money if that were possible.

Downloadable games are linked to your account, those games you can play from USB but only from your own account, or on any account when it's on your main Xbox360.

The point of installing a game is that you don't have to listen to the noise of the DVD player and that reading from disk/flash is a lot faster than reading from DVD.

Comment: They would also be breaking copyright law, so the lawsuits that would ensue would cause them to make even less money.